# counting combinations of {+1, -1} with constraints

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk

I'm trying to count the number of ways of arranging a sequence of length $N+2L$ made of "$+1$" and "$-1$", with the following two conditions:

1) the total has to sum to $N$

2) no partial sum is allowed to be negative or exceed $N$.

I can deal with the first condition by using $N+L$ occurrences of "$+1$" and $L$ occurrences of "$-1$" so that the number of possible combinations is $$\frac{(N+2L)!}{(N+L)!L!}={N+2L\choose L}$$
But some of these combinations have negative partial sums (e.g. if I start with a "$-1$"), or they exceed $N$ (e.g. if I start with all the "$+1$"), and I don't know how to count these and subtract them from the total.

EDIT: on mathworld.wolfram.com, the entry on [Nonnegative partial sums](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonnegativePartialSum.html) mentions the Catalan triangle, which solves "half" of the problem by counting the sequences whose partial sum is bounded below by zero. I would need to *additionally* bound it above.

Comment: Nice question but it should be better for math.stackexchange

Comment: Is is possible to ask a moderator to migrate it?

Comment: In Statistical Mechanics, there is a similar problem related to spins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be a generating function: some empirical calculations suggest you may be looking for the coefficient of $x^L$ in something like the expansion of $$\dfrac{1}{1-Nx+{N-1 \choose 2}x^2-{N-2 \choose 3}x^3+\cdots}=\dfrac{1}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\lceil N/2 \rceil}(-1)^k {N+1-k \choose k} x^k} $$

For example with $N=7$ you get: $$1+7\,x+34\,{x}^{2}+143\,{x}^{3}+560\,{x}^{4}+2108\,{x}^{5}+7752\,{x}^{6}+28101\,{x}^{7}+100947\,{x}^{8}+360526\,{x}^{9}+1282735\,{x}^{10}+4552624\,{x}^{11}+\cdots$$ which look like the values in [OEIS A005023](https://oeis.org/A005023) *"Number of walks of length 2n+7 in the path graph P_8 from one end to the other"*.

Comment: I don't quite understand what is M here. Is it $2N$?

Comment: $M$ should be $N$ - I will edit

Comment: Very nice! It seems to be working! The nice thing is that the sum at the denominator has a closed form (which is different for $N$ even or odd).